# Changing Bad Company 2 field of view

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2

I was told about the `settings.ini` file for BC:2 where you could increase your field of view.

The default value looks like:

```
Fov=55
```

I am wondering if there are any reasons I shouldn't do this, or if I will get banned for setting this value higher than 55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you cannot get banned for changing anything in the settings.ini file. But do back it up in case you make your game unplayable.**

BFBC2 can be played with different height ratio, so the FOV in the settings is the Vertical FOV, so use [This FOV calculator](http://www.rjdown.co.uk/projects/bfbc2/fovcalculator.php) to figure out the horizontal FOV if you want to set it to something specific horizontal.